# Changing the Userprofile

Tags: python, django

Hello i have UserSettings and the user as the possibility to use a ProfilePicture. The Problem is the User cannot change any of his profile Settings.  since i get the Error `Unique Constraint failed` or (thats what i get right now) `'int' object has no attribute '_committed'`

I think the problem is in the view but i dont know how to change it.

My model:

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):
profileimage = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_(u"Change Your Profilepicture"),upload_to=upload_location,
                    default=1, 
                    blank=True,
                    )

Info = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u"Tell us about yourself"),max_length=500,default="I'm a Human")
status = 
City = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u"Where are you from"),max_length=500,default='Earth')
user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=1)
objects = models.Manager()
class Meta:
    ordering =['-user']
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

My View:

```
@login_required
    def userprofiletwo(request):
    user = request.user
    form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = request.user
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your personal Settings are Updated')
        return redirect('userprofiletwo')
    context = {
    'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'userprofile/userprofiletwo.html', context)
```

I tried to change the OnetoOne field on the model to FeoreignKey or ManytoMany but this made new userprofiles instead of replacing the old information with new information.

Thanks in advise.

Comment: please review your indentation, in your code as in your question. And also what is this : `status = ` How don't you get a syntax error? And please proper location of the error, or a copy of the error dump.

Comment: Must read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the current profile into the form.

```
form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Comment: thanks. Yeah i tried that before. but it did not work. had to change "instance=request.user.profile" to "instance=user.usersettings". now everythings works just fine :)